# Multipeer Connectivity iOS over Wifi

Tags: ios, info.plist, multipeer-connectivity

I read somewhere that not all iOS devices support multipeer connectivity over WiFi, devices with lightning ports only support peer to peer over WiFi, others support it over Bluetooth. Is that correct? Although I couldn't find this in documentation, but in my app I would specifically want to ignore devices that don't support it. What keys I could add in info.plist to support only devices that support Multipeer over WiFi. If there is no specific key, what are the workaround keys that could be added?

Comment: you cannot specifically choose how your app connects using multipeer. As far as my knowledge goes, you cannot tell the framework to ignore a specific connection and use another. Under the hood, it picks the best available option, be it peer to peer wifi, infrastructure wifi or bluetooth

Comment: Well my question is that we know only lightning devices support peer to peer WiFi, how can we use info.plist keys to only support lightning devices? This is a workaround.